# Using delete [] on an object in an array

Tags: c++

How would I use delete on a specific class object in an array to ONLY delete that object and not the whole array?

This object will be no matter what be at the end of the array, so moving the other objects in the array doesn't matter also

EDIT:

To make it more clearer, I just want to free up the last element of the array for later use.

Comment: You shouldn't mutilate the array. You won't be able to call delete on it afterwards.

Comment: You can't do that (unless you agree to move everything except the last object to new array, and `delete[]` the old array). How about using `std::vector` instead?

Comment: Technically it *is* possible to do what you're asking for, but it would almost certainly not be what you mean.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to delete? Are you trying to delete a specific element in the array, or a member (pointer to instance) of a class in which the class is the member of the array? Post a code sample to clarify

Comment: I agree with @eladidan. What the OP is trying to achieve is unclear.

Comment: I want to take the object at the end of the array and copy it into another element of the array. But, I want to make sure the last array class object (not the actual element, it can stay) no longer is in the array when I print it later on. I have the copying part down - what would be the best way to remove the last object?

Comment: Just overwrite the last element with 0 and check for 0 before dereferencing any elements.

Comment: @quamrana : Not true if the array is not an array of pointers...

Comment: It is an array of pointers so I'll try that out. Thanks!

Comment: @user1754267 I edited my answer to that comment.

Comment: @user1754267 You're welcome.  But as Synxis says in his edited answer, you may be better off with `std::list` if you are regularly deleting elements part way through the container.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `std::vector` instead of a regular array if you need to do this. With `std::vector`, removing and destroying the final element is done via the `pop_back` method.

If you absolutely must use a regular array, and must destroy one object inside the array right now, you can placement-destroy that object and then construct a new one in its place. If you aren't sure what this means or how to do it, you probably should  be using `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the last element of the array to somewhere else, simply do that and then ignore the last element. You cannot remove it. Usually you have a counter variable somewhere that holds the amount of elements currently in the array. So when you "remove" the last element, simply decrement that counter by 1.

FYI, `std::vector` works exactly the same way. (And you should be using `std::vector` to begin with anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

An array allocated with the `new[]` directive can only be released with the `delete[]` directive. Any other attempt to release part of or the entire array (`free`, `delete` etc.) is undefined behaviour. 
If you want to be able to free a specific element in the array then you are better off looking into using an stl container such as `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::set`, `std::map` etc. Each has different properties and is appropriate for a different task, but all support fast deletion of elements (except `vector` which only supports "fast" delteion of the last element but since that is exactly what you wanted then its a good option) and in fact "hide" the allocation of elements for  you.

Comment: "Any other attempt... will fail." Actually, it may fail, or not to fail, or call your grandma

Answer (score 0):

If the array is like

```
object* array = new object[n];
```

Then you cannot delete an element of it. You can move the elements by using `memcpy()`, but not change the size of the array.

Using `new` or `delete` on an array item will result in heap corruption in the majority of cases. As suggested, you should use `std::vector`.

If the array is an array of pointers to objects, then you can `delete` a pointed object *but* you cannot delete the pointer itself (see first part of this answer).

EDIT: a comment from the author of the question specify that he wants to remove the last element of a pointer array.

You can set the last pointer to 0 and check:

```
pointers[size - 1] = 0;
// later, when using the array
if(pointers[i]) // do smth
```

Using `std::vector` will be more easy. Also, if you deletions are frequent enough, you should consider using `std::list`.